# How to build a project with Gatsby and PSPDFKIT

Tags: node.js, gatsby, pspdfkit

I have a web app built on Gatsby I have been integrating with PSPDFKIT. All goes well when doing `npm run start`, but when testing a build, PSPDFKIT is not loading correctly. On Firefox, I am getting the following errors.

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:9000/component---src-pages-document-template-index-tsx-e6eae06a018fd9e345ed.js:34656:17u@http:/localhost:9000/component---src-pages-document-template-index-tsx-e6eae06a018fd9e345ed.js:34664:8945/%3C/%3C@http:/localhost:9000/component---src-pages-document-template-index-tsx-e6eae06a018fd9e345ed.js:99258:23o@http:/localhost:9000/component---src-pages-document-template-index-tsx-e6eae06a018fd9e345ed.js:14665:19945/%3C/%3C@http:/localhost:9000/component---src-pages-document-template-index-tsx-e6eae06a018fd9e345ed.js:53209:17o@http:/localhost:9000/component---src-pages-document-template-index-tsx-e6eae06a018fd9e345ed.js:14665:19945/%3C/%3C@http:/localhost:9000/component---src-pages-document-template-index-tsx-e6eae06a018fd9e345ed.js:14878:12945/%3C@http:/localhost:9000/component---src-pages-document-template-index-tsx-e6eae06a018fd9e345ed.js:14879:4945/%3C@http:/localhost:9000/component---src-pages-document-template-index-tsx-e6eae06a018fd9e345ed.js:14636:28945@http:/localhost:9000/component---src-pages-document-template-index-tsx-e6eae06a018fd9e345ed.js:14637:2__webpack_require__@http:/localhost:9000/webpack-runtime-6b87f13ad39d10d73a8c.js:85:30539@http:/localhost:9000/component---src-pages-document-template-index-tsx-e6eae06a018fd9e345ed.js:1207:35__webpack_require__@http:/localhost:9000/webpack-runtime-6b87f13ad39d10d73a8c.js:85:30promise%20callback*componentSrcPagesDocumentTemplateIndexTsx@http:/localhost:9000/app-92e6fce1f37094f47582.js:28583:4617loadComponent@http:/localhost:9000/app-92e6fce1f37094f47582.js:9797:1467loadPage/inFlight%3C@http:/localhost:9000/app-92e6fce1f37094f47582.js:9787:196promise%20callback*loadPage@http:/localhost:9000/app-92e6fce1f37094f47582.js:9785:323loadPage@http:/localhost:9000/app-92e6fce1f37094f47582.js:9803:179@http:/localhost:9000/app-92e6fce1f37094f47582.js:46978:377promise%20callback*@http:/localhost:9000/app-92e6fce1f37094f47582.js:46961:472__webpack_require__@http:/localhost:9000/webpack-runtime-6b87f13ad39d10d73a8c.js:85:30checkDeferredModules@http:/localhost:9000/webpack-runtime-6b87f13ad39d10d73a8c.js:46:23webpackJsonpCallback@http:/localhost:9000/webpack-runtime-6b87f13ad39d10d73a8c.js:33:19@http:/localhost:9000/pspdfkit-lib/chunk-standalone-375f5232b6e41a45.js”.
Uncaught (in promise) ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 60 failed.
(error: http://localhost:9000/component---src-pages-document-templat…lhost:9000/pspdfkit-lib/chunk-standalone-375f5232b6e41a45.js)
    e pspdfkit.js:369
    t pspdfkit.js:84260
    s pspdfkit.js:36042
    _invoke pspdfkit.js:36022
    e pspdfkit.js:36075
    n pspdfkit.js:5194
    c pspdfkit.js:5211
    exports pspdfkit.js:5218
    exports pspdfkit.js:5207
    oO pspdfkit.js:84494
    load pspdfkit.js:84903
    _callee7$ usePdfViewer.ts:230
    Babel 10
    usePdfViewer usePdfViewer.ts:259
    React 28
    AuthProvider AuthProvider.tsx:38
    promise callback*AuthProvider/< AuthProvider.tsx:38
    React 10
    Webpack 12
```

On Chrome I am randomly getting a similar error.

```
Uncaught (in promise) ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 60 failed.
(error: http://localhost:9000/component---src-pages-document-template-index-tsx-e6eae06a018fd9e345ed.js:34656:17%20%20%20%20at%20u%20(http:/localhost:9000/pspdfkit-lib/chunk-standalone-375f5232b6e41a45.js)
    at Function.o.e (http://localhost:9000/component---src-pages-document-template-index-tsx-e6eae06a018fd9e345ed.js:14807:17)
    at http://localhost:9000/component---src-pages-document-template-index-tsx-e6eae06a018fd9e345ed.js:98698:39
    at s (http://localhost:9000/component---src-pages-document-template-index-tsx-e6eae06a018fd9e345ed.js:50480:20)
    at Generator._invoke (http://localhost:9000/component---src-pages-document-template-index-tsx-e6eae06a018fd9e345ed.js:50460:23)
    at Generator.t.<computed> [as next] (http://localhost:9000/component---src-pages-document-template-index-tsx-e6eae06a018fd9e345ed.js:50513:25)
    at n (http://localhost:9000/component---src-pages-document-template-index-tsx-e6eae06a018fd9e345ed.js:19632:21)
    at c (http://localhost:9000/component---src-pages-document-template-index-tsx-e6eae06a018fd9e345ed.js:19649:13)
    at http://localhost:9000/component---src-pages-document-template-index-tsx-e6eae06a018fd9e345ed.js:19656:11
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9000/component---src-pages-document-template-index-tsx-e6eae06a018fd9e345ed.js:19645:16)
```

I have been testing the build using `gatsby serve`. Also, I am serving the required files as mentioned [here](https://pspdfkit.com/guides/web/current/standalone/adding-to-your-project/). To avoid a `Error: Windows is not defined`, I have modified the webpack config as mentioned [here](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/#fixing-third-party-modules).

I should mention that I have done the same kind of tests with this [example](https://github.com/PSPDFKit/pspdfkit-web-example-gatsbyjs), provided by PSPDFKIT, and have been getting the same kind of error (more consistently on firefox).

Comment: Can you provide the `gatsby-node.js` where you modified the webpack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, with help from PSPDFKIT support, I solved this issue. All I had to do was add a configuration option when doing `PSPDFKit.load`. By the end I had some like this:

```
PSPDFKit.load({
    ...
    baseUrl: location.origin + "/",
    ...
});
```

It seems the library fails guessing the `baseUrl` when not set.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your issue comes from the `Error: Windows is not defined` since, as far as I know, and based on some [Gatsby staters that use it](https://github.com/PSPDFKit/pspdfkit-web-example-gatsbyjs), PSPDFKIT it's not needed to add a `null` loader in webpack's configuration, so remove it.

What I think you are missing is to add some manual scripts. [According to the documentation](https://github.com/PSPDFKit/pspdfkit-web-example-gatsbyjs#pspdfkit-assets):

> In order to make the example work, the PSPDFKit assets need to be
> copied from their original location in `./node_modules/pspdfkit/dist` to
> ./static. This is done automatically from a postinstall script in
> located in `./scripts/copy-pspdfkit-files.js`.
>
> In case copying the files fails, you can copy them manually:
>
> - Copy `./node_modules/pspdfkit/dist/pspdfkit.js` to `./static/pspdfkit.js`.
> - Copy `./node_modules/pspdfkit/dist/pspdfkit-lib/` to `./static/pspdfkit-lib/`.

This is needed in order to work with PSPDFKit assets, so. Create a `copy-pspdfkit-files.js` file in `/script` folder in the root of your project with the following content:

```
const ncp = require("ncp").ncp;
const fs = require("fs");

    ncp(
      "./node_modules/pspdfkit/dist/pspdfkit-lib",
      "./static/pspdfkit-lib",
      err => {
        err && console.error(err);
      }
    );
```

This file will be automatically called in a postinstall script, from PSPDFKIT dependency, but as the docs said, if the process fail copy them in the `/static` folder.

In addition, based on your error:

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:9000/component---src-pages-document-template-index-tsx-e6eae06a018fd9e345ed.js:34656:17u@http:/localhost:9000/component---src-pages-document-template-index-tsx-e6eae06a018fd9e345ed.js:34664:8945/%3C/%3C@http:/localhost:9000/component---src-pages-document-template-index-tsx-e6eae06a018fd9e345ed.js:99258:23o@http:/localhost:9000/component---src-pages-document-template-index-tsx-e6eae06a018fd9e345ed.js:14665:19945/%3C/%3C@http:/localhost:9000/component---src-pages-document-template-index-tsx-e6eae06a018fd9e345ed.js:53209:17o@http:/localhost:9000/component---src-pages-document-template-index-tsx-e6eae06a018fd9e345ed.js:14665:19945/%3C/%3C@http:/localhost:9000/component---src-pages-document-template-index-tsx-e6eae06a018fd9e345ed.js:14878:12945/%3C@http:/localhost:9000/component---src-pages-document-template-index-tsx-e6eae06a018fd9e345ed.js:14879:4945/%3C@http:/localhost:9000/component---src-pages-document-template-index-tsx-e6eae06a018fd9e345ed.js:14636:28945@http:/localhost:9000/component---src-pages-document-template-index-tsx-e6eae06a018fd9e345ed.js:14637:2__webpack_require__@http:/localhost:9000/webpack-runtime-6b87f13ad39d10d73a8c.js:85:30539@http:/localhost:9000/component---src-pages-document-template-index-tsx-e6eae06a018fd9e345ed.js:1207:35__webpack_require__@http:/localhost:9000/webpack-runtime-6b87f13ad39d10d73a8c.js:85:30promise%20callback*componentSrcPagesDocumentTemplateIndexTsx@http:/localhost:9000/app-92e6fce1f37094f47582.js:28583:4617loadComponent@http:/localhost:9000/app-92e6fce1f37094f47582.js:9797:1467loadPage/inFlight%3C@http:/localhost:9000/app-92e6fce1f37094f47582.js:9787:196promise%20callback*loadPage@http:/localhost:9000/app-92e6fce1f37094f47582.js:9785:323loadPage@http:/localhost:9000/app-92e6fce1f37094f47582.js:9803:179@http:/localhost:9000/app-92e6fce1f37094f47582.js:46978:377promise%20callback*@http:/localhost:9000/app-92e6fce1f37094f47582.js:46961:472__webpack_require__@http:/localhost:9000/webpack-runtime-6b87f13ad39d10d73a8c.js:85:30checkDeferredModules@http:/localhost:9000/webpack-runtime-6b87f13ad39d10d73a8c.js:46:23webpackJsonpCallback@http:/localhost:9000/webpack-runtime-6b87f13ad39d10d73a8c.js:33:19@http:/localhost:9000/pspdfkit-lib/chunk-standalone-375f5232b6e41a45.js”.
```

Take a look at the starter I've provided and compare your queries.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I have done the same kind of tests with this [starter](https://github.com/PSPDFKit/pspdfkit-web-example-gatsbyjs) and have been getting the same kind of error (more consistently on firefox).

Comment: Did you copy both files in the `static` folder?

Comment: I have just copied both, the file and the folder, manually as the `copy-pspdfkit-files.js` only copies the folder, but I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

We have now updated our Gatsby example to address this issue. Please, let us know if it still doesn't work for you:

https://github.com/PSPDFKit/pspdfkit-web-example-gatsbyjs

In the future, I'd recommend to reach out directly to our support platform: https://support.pspdfkit.com